# How create fix pagination number

Tags: php, pagination

I have found code for pagination .Here first time pagination three numbers show ,like:
[1] 2 3 next >>

If I click on number 2 it shows:
<< prev 1 [2] 3 4 next >>

But I need three numbers will show  all time if there are  more than three pages.Like,
<< prev 1 [2] 3 4 next >>

page.php

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("mydatabase");

$rowsperpage = 4; // how many items per page
$pagerange = 2;// how many pages to show in page link

if (isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
   // cast var as int
   $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
} else {
   // default page num
   $currentpage = 1;
} // end if
// the offset of the list, based on current page
$offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

$qury1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM audit";
$result_page = mysql_query($qury1) or die(mysql_error());
$r = mysql_fetch_row($result_page);
$numrows = $r[0];
$totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

if ($currentpage > $totalpages) {
   // set current page to last page
   $currentpage = $totalpages;
} // end if
// if current page is less than first page...
if ($currentpage < 1)  {
   // set current page to first page
   $currentpage = 1;
} // end if

/*PUT YOUR SQL CODE HERE AS WELL AS EVERYTHING THAT SHOULD BE ON THE PAGE.
THE FOLLOWING GOES BELOW AT THE BOTTOM OF YOUR CONTENT:*/

$result_page = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM audit");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result_page);

if ($num_rows<1) {
} else {
    echo "Page ".$currentpage." of ".$totalpages."<br>";
    if ($currentpage > 1) {
        // show << link to go back to page 1
        echo " <a href='page.php?currentpage=1'><<</a> ";
        // get previous page num
        $prevpage = $currentpage - 1;
        // show < link to go back to 1 page
        echo " <a href='page.php?currentpage=$prevpage'>prev</a> ";
    } // end if

    // loop to show links to range of pages around current page
    for ($x = ($currentpage-$pagerange); $x < (($currentpage+$pagerange)+1); $x++) {
        // if it's a valid page number...
        if (($x > 0) && ($x <= $totalpages)) {
            // if we're on current page...
            if ($x == $currentpage) {
                // 'highlight' it but don't make a link
                echo " [<b>$x</b>] ";
                // if not current page...
            } else {
                // make it a link
                echo " <a href='page.php?currentpage=$x'>$x</a> ";
            } // end else
        } // end if
    } // end for

    // if not on last page, show forward and last page links
    if ($currentpage != $totalpages) {
        // get next page
        $nextpage = $currentpage + 1;
        // echo forward link for next page
        echo " <a href='page.php?currentpage=$nextpage'>next</a> ";
        // echo forward link for lastpage
        echo " <a href='page.php?currentpage=$totalpages'>>></a> ";
    } // end if
} // end else
```

Comment: So, while you now have `<< prev 1 [2] 3 4 next >>`, you need `<< prev 1 [2] 3 4 next >>` instead? Is there an error in the question or are you just not being very clear about it?

Comment: sorry , I need 3 number will show all time. Like, << prev 1 [2] 3 next >>  ,<< prev 2 [3] 4 next >> etc . now problem is if click on a page number then total page number are increasing.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your code stores the number of visible pages in the `$pagerange` variable. In this case it is set to `2`, which leads to two pages being shown on each side of the current page. For instance, if we're on page 4, the links would be `<< prev 2 3 [4] 5 6 next >>`.

Therefore, setting it to `1` will make the number of visible pages three:

```
$pagerange = 1;
```

The links would then be `<< prev 3 [4] 5 next >>`.

However, when we're on the first or the last page, this setting will only show one additional page number in the links section: `[1] 2 next >>`.

This requires an additional increase to the range in the case of first and last page:

```
if ($currentpage == 1 || $currentpage == $totalpages) {
    $pagerange = 2;
}
```

This segment should be placed after all the checks of `$currentpage` but before any of the links are printed. I would place it right before the long comment `/*PUT YOUR SQL CODE HERE...`.

Now, we will have `[1] 2 3 next >>`.